# How to make ASP.NET chart control automatically resizable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, charts

I need to create a web page producing a chart control (that will be filled with appropriate data). It should be made the way that autoresizes when it is placed into `<iframe>`. As an example, we can look how YouTube videos get resized inside `<iframe>` (e.g., `<iframe width="854" height="510" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9EcjWd-O4jI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`).

The problem is that I don't know any way to let the chart know the height and width of the `<iframe>` (e.g., `width="854" height="510"`).

Any suggestions are appreciated!